# Performance issue when building a multi branch tree in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, memory-management, tree

I'm converting a flat hierarchy of objects into nested objects based on parent node ids.

The problem is that when I input more complex structures (more and deeper children), the process takes a really long time to finish.

Maybe it's related to memory or other inefficient use of recursion or redundancy? I'm not sure.

The code:

```js
const people = [
  {
    id: '738a8f8a',
    parentNode: null
  },
  {
    id: 'd18fd69c',
    parentNode: '738a8f8a'
  },
  {
    id: 'b507c11d',
    parentNode: '738a8f8a'
  },
  {
    id: '171d4709',
    parentNode: 'b507c11d'
  },
  {
    id: '471b1cee',
    parentNode: 'b507c11d'
  }
];

function getBase(base) {
  for (const person of base) {
    if (person['parentNode'] === null) {
      return person;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function getChildren(parent) {
  const values = people.filter((person) => {
    return person['parentNode'] === parent['id'];
  });
  return Object.values(values);
}

function buildHierarchy(base = null) {
  if (base === null) {
    base = getBase(people);
    if (base === null) {
      return null;
    }
  }
  const children = getChildren(base).map((child) => {
    return buildHierarchy(child);
  });
  base['childrenNodes'] = children;
  return base;
}

console.log(buildHierarchy());
```

And the output of the console.log above:

```
  {
    id: '738a8f8a',
    parentNode: null
    childrenNodes: [
      {
        id: 'd18fd69c',
        parentNode: '738a8f8a',
        childrenNodes: [],
      },
      {
        id: 'b507c11d',
        parentNode: '738a8f8a',
        childrenNodes: [
          {
            id: '171d4709',
            parentNode: 'b507c11d',
            childrenNodes: [],
          },
          {
            id: '471b1cee',
            parentNode: 'b507c11d',
            childrenNodes: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  };
```

Comment: Would you be able to share sample data that takes a long time to process? Also, could you be more specific about _"a long time"_? I think the bottleneck is the use of `filter` in the `getChildren` function, but it would be useful to test with real data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While writing this answer, I saw @cbr's, and thought it was the same logic. But not entirely, and there seems to be a sensible performance difference *(in Chrome at least)*, so I'll still post this one

I was not able to test this with real data that takes a long time to process, but I think your bottleneck is the use of `filter` in the `getChildren` function. For every single person, you are going through the entire `people` Array.

I think the time could be reduced by pre-processing the data only once, before building the hierarchy. To do this, we could create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), where each key is the ID of a person, and the value is an Array of its children.

This could be implemented like this:

```
// For each person
const childMap = people.reduce((map, person) => {
  // If its parentNode is not already in the map
  if (!map.has(person.parentNode)) {
    // Add it
    map.set(person.parentNode, []);
  }
  // Then, push the current person into that parent ID's children Array
  map.get(person.parentNode).push(person);
  return map;
}, new Map());
```

Then, your `getChildren` function would look like this:

```
function getChildren(parent) {
  return childMap.get(parent.id) || [];
}
```

Here is the full example, running 100.000 times in a row:

```js
const people = [
  {
    id: '738a8f8a',
    parentNode: null
  },
  {
    id: 'd18fd69c',
    parentNode: '738a8f8a'
  },
  {
    id: 'b507c11d',
    parentNode: '738a8f8a'
  },
  {
    id: '171d4709',
    parentNode: 'b507c11d'
  },
  {
    id: '471b1cee',
    parentNode: 'b507c11d'
  }
];

const childMap = people.reduce((map, person) => {
  if (!map.has(person.parentNode)) {
    map.set(person.parentNode, []);
  }
  map.get(person.parentNode).push(person);
  return map;
}, new Map());

function getBase(base) {
  for (const person of base) {
    if (person.parentNode === null) {
      return person;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function getChildren(parent) {
  return childMap.get(parent.id) || [];
}

function buildHierarchy(base = null) {
  if (base === null) {
    base = getBase(people);
    if (base === null) {
      return null;
    }
  }
  const children = getChildren(base);
  base.childrenNodes = children.map(buildHierarchy);
  return base;
}

console.time('x');
for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) buildHierarchy();
console.timeEnd('x');
```

Your code, running 100.000 times in a row:

```js
const people = [
  {
    id: '738a8f8a',
    parentNode: null
  },
  {
    id: 'd18fd69c',
    parentNode: '738a8f8a'
  },
  {
    id: 'b507c11d',
    parentNode: '738a8f8a'
  },
  {
    id: '171d4709',
    parentNode: 'b507c11d'
  },
  {
    id: '471b1cee',
    parentNode: 'b507c11d'
  }
];

function getBase(base) {
  for (const person of base) {
    if (person['parentNode'] === null) {
      return person;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function getChildren(parent) {
  const values = people.filter((person) => {
    return person['parentNode'] === parent['id'];
  });
  return Object.values(values);
}

function buildHierarchy(base = null) {
  if (base === null) {
    base = getBase(people);
    if (base === null) {
      return null;
    }
  }
  const children = getChildren(base).map((child) => {
    return buildHierarchy(child);
  });
  base['childrenNodes'] = children;
  return base;
}

console.time('x');
for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) buildHierarchy();
console.timeEnd('x');
```

@cbr's code, running 100.000 times in a row:

```js
const people = [
  {
    id: "738a8f8a",
    parentNode: null,
  },
  {
    id: "d18fd69c",
    parentNode: "738a8f8a",
  },
  {
    id: "b507c11d",
    parentNode: "738a8f8a",
  },
  {
    id: "171d4709",
    parentNode: "b507c11d",
  },
  {
    id: "471b1cee",
    parentNode: "b507c11d",
  },
];

function buildNodeChildLookup(people) {
  const nodeIdToNode = people.reduce((map, curr) => {
    map.set(curr.id, curr);
    return map;
  }, new Map());

  return people.reduce((map, curr) => {
    const children = map.get(curr.parentNode) || [];
    const childNode = nodeIdToNode.get(curr.id);
    children.push(childNode);
    map.set(curr.parentNode, children);
    return map;
  }, new Map());
}

function buildHierarchy(node, nodeToChildren) {
  const children = nodeToChildren.get(node.id) || [];
  return {
    ...node,
    childNodes: children.map((child) => buildHierarchy(child, nodeToChildren)),
  };
}

// assume only one root!
const nodeIdToChildren = buildNodeChildLookup(people);
const root = nodeIdToChildren.get(null)[0];

console.time('x');
for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) buildHierarchy(root, nodeIdToChildren);
console.timeEnd('x');
```

Comment: Very good! The performance difference is due to my implementation making a copy of the objects (`{ ...node }`). If the implementation is changed to mutate `node.childNodes` directly, the times are comparable.

Comment: @cbr Yes, I wasn't sure at first, but we really have the exact same stucture for the Map  (except I don't add keys for leaves). I left the rest of the OP's code unchanged, I think they don't mind mutating the original data

Answer (score 1):

I think that the main bottleneck is algorithmic here. `getChildren` iterates over the entire `people` array, and it gets called for every single node. As the amount of elements in `people` increases, this cost adds up. It's been a long time since I last did algorithmic analysis, but I would throw an educated guess that the current implementation's [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) is O(n^2).

I would solve this by using, for example, `Map`. I would go through the entire array once or twice to build a `Map` of node->children[], so that we can just do a fast O(1) lookup when recursing. This will help the time complexity but as a trade-off requires more memory because all of the elements are stored more than once in memory.

Here's an example:

```
function buildNodeChildLookup(people) {
  const nodeIdToNode = people.reduce((map, curr) => {
    map.set(curr.id, curr);
    return map;
  }, new Map());

  return people.reduce((map, curr) => {
    const children = map.get(curr.parentNode) || [];
    const childNode = nodeIdToNode.get(curr.id);
    children.push(childNode);
    map.set(curr.parentNode, children);
    return map;
  }, new Map());
}

// assume only one root!
const nodeIdToChildren = buildNodeChildLookup(people);

console.log(nodeIdToChildren)
// Map {
//   null => [ { id: '738a8f8a', parentNode: null } ],
//   '738a8f8a' => [
//     { id: 'd18fd69c', parentNode: '738a8f8a' },
//     { id: 'b507c11d', parentNode: '738a8f8a' }
//   ],
//   'b507c11d' => [
//     { id: '171d4709', parentNode: 'b507c11d' },
//     { id: '471b1cee', parentNode: 'b507c11d' }
//   ]
// }
```

Now that we have a fast lookup of "node id" -> "child nodes", we can just recurse from the root (the single node whose parent is `null`):

```
function buildHierarchy(node, nodeToChildren) {
  const children = nodeToChildren.get(node.id) || [];
  return {
    ...node,
    childNodes: children.map((child) => buildHierarchy(child, nodeToChildren)),
  };
}
```

As you can see, the `buildHierarchy` function is now much lighter as it just does a quick lookup for the node's children.

Putting it all together:

```js
const people = [
  {
    id: "738a8f8a",
    parentNode: null,
  },
  {
    id: "d18fd69c",
    parentNode: "738a8f8a",
  },
  {
    id: "b507c11d",
    parentNode: "738a8f8a",
  },
  {
    id: "171d4709",
    parentNode: "b507c11d",
  },
  {
    id: "471b1cee",
    parentNode: "b507c11d",
  },
];

function buildNodeChildLookup(people) {
  const nodeIdToNode = people.reduce((map, curr) => {
    map.set(curr.id, curr);
    return map;
  }, new Map());

  return people.reduce((map, curr) => {
    const children = map.get(curr.parentNode) || [];
    const childNode = nodeIdToNode.get(curr.id);
    children.push(childNode);
    map.set(curr.parentNode, children);
    return map;
  }, new Map());
}

function buildHierarchy(node, nodeToChildren) {
  const children = nodeToChildren.get(node.id) || [];
  return {
    ...node,
    childNodes: children.map((child) => buildHierarchy(child, nodeToChildren)),
  };
}

// assume only one root!
const nodeIdToChildren = buildNodeChildLookup(people);
const root = nodeIdToChildren.get(null)[0];
console.log(buildHierarchy(root, nodeIdToChildren));
```

If this doesn't help, I would recommend profiling your application with Chrome's developer tools. They have great tools for finding which functions take time, or which functions exhaust memory.